# Xgboost with simple time series dataframe Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, xgboost

I have this dataframe with the hourly production of a plant. I have many 0 values in the dataframe (sometimes the plant doesn't work for external reasons).
If anyone want to have a glance on the dataframe here the link (https://www.mediafire.com/file/55915xs2acdl7h4/Dataframe.zip/file)

[image: df and his distribution]

I would like to make a prediction for the next 24 hours, but I'm having many troubles with xgboost. After splitting the data (X_train/y_train; X_test/y_test) the algorithm is stuck.
[image]

1) Should I change algorithm?
2) Am I missing some parameter tuning steps?

Comment: is there any input you can use? the trend has a clear exponential decay every time starts the operation. Shutdowns are easy to track with amps of your pumps/compressors

Comment: What do you mean by input? unfortunately I dont have any other data/features. Regarding shutdowns can you explain more? I tried to convert zeros in nan but I get an error:  'KeyError: 'best_msg' '

Comment: Can you share the data you have?

Comment: Sure! https://www.mediafire.com/file/55915xs2acdl7h4/Dataframe.zip/file

Comment: There are 2 versions of the same dataset, a) is with hourly columns and 1 row for each day. version b is rows for each hour and only one column as in the question

Comment: xgboost won't work with this data unless you do some feature engineering (create temporal features for every target value)